# Parsing timestamp using csv module and datetime module

Tags: python, csv, parsing, time

I'm having some trouble with the `datetime` module in Python. I have this data from a csv file:

```
user_id,timestamp
563,0:00:21
671,0:00:26
780,0:00:28
```

This is my code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

path = "/home/haldrik/dev/python/data/dataset.csv"
file = open(path, newline='')

reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

header = next(reader) # Ignore first row.

data = []
for row in reader:
    # row = [user_id, timestamp]
    user_id = row[0]
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S').time()
    
    data.append([user_id, timestamp])
```

That code throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/haldrik/dev/python/instances_web_site.py", line 15, in <module>
    date = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S').time()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

I can't find where the error is. I can see that the data format fits the time format specified.

Decanting the cvs import step, I can ensure that it works, see this snippet of code (not included into the above code):

```
data_import = [row for row in reader]
print(data_import[0])
```

It outputs this:

```
['563','0:00:21']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have an issue with one or more of the values in the timestamp column, where a row looks like `440,` and will result in `time data '' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'`
- Wrap `date = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S').time()` in a `try-except` block.

#### `test.csv`

```py
user_id,timestamp
563,0:00:21
671,0:00:26
780,0:00:28
440,
```

#### Code

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

path = "test.csv"
file = open(path, newline='')

reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

header = next(reader) # Ignore first row.

data = []
for row in reader:
    # row = [user_id, timestamp]
    user_id = row[0]
    try:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S').time()
    except ValueError as e:
        timestamp = row[1]
#         continue  # use this if you do not want the row added to data, comment it out otherwise
    
    data.append([user_id, timestamp])


print(data)
[out]:
[['563', datetime.time(0, 0, 21)], ['671', datetime.time(0, 0, 26)], ['780', datetime.time(0, 0, 28)], ['440', '']]
```

Comment: You were right, the csv file is full of empty data just with the comma ('','') at the end of the file.